# Implement pool queue selenium grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, connection-pooling, selenium-grid, connection-pool

In automation test single Cucumber TestNG runner is assigning threads to grid properly. However when we have multiple jobs accessing same hub url, it's causing time out. If we implement a pool queue, Do I need to queue testNg runner class or threads?. If my first job has 50 tests and 100 nodes then do I need to wait till 50 tests are run? How can I utilize idle nodes?

Also what api's that I can use from selenium hub to implement above logic?

Comment: You can provide the testng.xml with a thread count for how many test you want to run <suite name="Suite1" thread-count="20" >